# Displaying form information with PHP classes

Tags: php, forms, class, submit

I am trying to display the information put in a form. Here is my code that is messing me up:

```
<?php
//include the person class
require ('objects/classes/person.class.php');

$person = new Person();

//set person attributes
$person->first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
$person->last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
$full_name = $person->retrieve_full_name();
//display the name
echo "Your full name is " . $full_name  . ". <br />";
echo "Your first name is " . $person . ". <br />";
echo "Your last name is " . $person . ".";


?>
```

This is my class code:

```
class Person {

//private attributes
private $first_name;
private $last_name;

//get function
public function __get($name){
    return $this->$name;
}
//set function
public function __set($name, $value){
    $this->$name=$value;    

}

public function retrieve_full_name(){
    return $full_name = $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;

}
}
?>
```

I also get this error when submitted: 
Your full name is www dddd. 
Catchable fatal error: Object of class Person could not be converted to string in /home/gaddough/cit21500/exercises/objects/login.php on line 13

I know its an easy fix somewhere but I can't figure it out Any help would be awesome!

Comment: `return $full_name = $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;` this makes no sense imo and should be equal to `return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to print your $person object as a string on these lines:

```
echo "Your first name is " . $person . ". <br />";
echo "Your last name is " . $person . ".";
```

Try this, to print the first_name and last_name instance variables instead:

```
echo "Your first name is " . $person->first_name . ". <br />";
echo "Your last name is " . $person->last_name . ".";
```

Comment: Yep. That works just fine. I knew that it was something that simple! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note is you are right in your approach, but the execution is wrong. If you look at your code you will see you use local variables in the functions (Methods) and never touch the private member variables.

Your `person` class needs to set the $first_name and $last_name and then when you call your  "get" function you can grab these variables back.

```
class person
{
private $first_name;
private $last_name;

public function set_name( $first, $second )
{
    if( !is_empty($first) )
    {
        $this->first_name = $first;
    }
    if( !is_empty($second) )
    {
        $this->last_name = $second;
    }
}

public function get_full_name()
{
    return $this->first_name ." ". $this->last_name;
}

}
```

And to test it (because I did not - I simply wrote this as an example)

```
<?php
$person = new person();

$person->set_name( "James", "Dean" );

echo $person->get_full_name();
?>
```

And of course you can write get's for first name and last name separately :)

Good luck!